# Error when trying to install brew -e:194

Tags: macos

I received an error when installing brew and I'm not sure what it is:

```
 overminds-MacBook-Air:~ overmind$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
 ==> This script will install:
 /usr/local/bin/brew
 /usr/local/Library/...
 /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
 Press ENTER to continue or any other key to abort
 ==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
 -e:194: command not found: Error: /usr/bin/xcode-select returned unexpected error. --version
```

Do I have to worry about it? (I'm just following a tutorial installing git).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that `xcode-select` is missing, which therefore means that Xcode is not installed.

[Install Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), then run it and allow it to install components, then retry the installation.